# 'Unable to deserialize content' when updating Microsoft calendar events in batch on retry

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working on an application based on .NET Framework 4.8. I'm using [Microsoft Batching API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching?view=graph-rest-1.0). The below are code snippets

```
 public async Task<List<BatchResponse>> UpdateEventsInBatchAsync(string accessToken, Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, OfficeEvent>> absEvents)
    {
        var httpMethod = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
        var batches = GetUpdateRequestBatches(absEvents, httpMethod);

        var graphClient = GetGraphClient(accessToken);

        var batchResponses = new List<BatchResponse>();
        foreach (var batch in batches)
        {
            try
            {
                var batchResponseList = await ExecuteBatchRequestAsync(graphClient, batch).ConfigureAwait(false);
                batchResponses.AddRange(batchResponseList);
            }
            catch (ClientException exc)
            {
                _logService.LogException("Error while processing update batch", exc);
                batchResponses.Add(new BatchResponse
                { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ReasonPhrase = exc.Message });
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                _logService.LogException("Error while processing update batch", exc);
                batchResponses.Add(new BatchResponse { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ReasonPhrase = exc.Message });
            }
        }

        return batchResponses;
    }
```

The respective methods used in the above code are mentioned below in respective order-

**GetUpdateRequestBatches**

```
 private IEnumerable<BatchRequestContent> GetUpdateRequestBatches(Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, OfficeEvent>> absEvents, HttpMethod httpMethod)
    {
        var batches = new List<BatchRequestContent>();
        var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();

        const int maxNoBatchItems = 20;
        var batchItemsCount = 0;

        foreach (var kvp in absEvents)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write($"{kvp.Key} --- ");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_serializer.SerializeObject(kvp.Value.Item2));

            var requestUri = $"{_msOfficeBaseApiUrl}/me/events/{kvp.Value.Item1}";
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, requestUri)
            {
                Content = _serializer.SerializeAsJsonContent(kvp.Value.Item2)
            };
             
            var requestStep = new BatchRequestStep(kvp.Key.ToString(), httpRequestMessage);
            batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(requestStep);
            batchItemsCount++;

            // Max number of 20 request per batch. So we need to send out multiple batches.
            if (batchItemsCount > 0 && batchItemsCount % maxNoBatchItems == 0)
            {
                batches.Add(batchRequestContent);
                batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();
                batchItemsCount = 0;
            }
        }

        if (batchRequestContent.BatchRequestSteps.Count < maxNoBatchItems)
        {
            batches.Add(batchRequestContent);
        }

        if (batches.Count == 0)
        {
            batches.Add(batchRequestContent);
        }

        return batches;
    }
```

**GetGraphClient**

```
  private static GraphServiceClient GetGraphClient(string accessToken)
    {
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(requestMessage =>
         {
             requestMessage
                 .Headers
                 .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

             return Task.FromResult(0);
         }));

        return graphClient;
    }
```

**ExecuteBatchRequestAsync**

```
private async Task<List<BatchResponse>> ExecuteBatchRequestAsync(IBaseClient graphClient, BatchRequestContent batch)
    {
        BatchResponseContent response = await graphClient.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batch);

        Dictionary<string, HttpResponseMessage> responses = await response.GetResponsesAsync();

        var batchResponses = new List<BatchResponse>();
        var failedReqKeys = new Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>();

        foreach (var key in responses.Keys)
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMsg = await response.GetResponseByIdAsync(key))
            {
                var responseContent = await httpResponseMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                string eventId = null;
                var reasonPhrase = httpResponseMsg.ReasonPhrase;

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(responseContent))
                {
                    var eventResponse = JObject.Parse(responseContent);
                    eventId = (string)eventResponse["id"];

                    // If still null, then might error have occurred
                    if (eventId == null)
                    {
                        var errorResponse = _serializer.DeserializeObject<ErrorResponse>(responseContent);
                        var error = errorResponse?.Error;
                        if (error != null)
                        {
                            if (httpResponseMsg.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)429)
                            {
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{httpResponseMsg.StatusCode} {httpResponseMsg.Content}");
                                var executionDelay = httpResponseMsg.Headers.RetryAfter.Delta ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                                failedReqKeys.Add(key, executionDelay);

                                continue;
                            }

                            reasonPhrase = $"{error.Code} - {error.Message}";
                        }
                    }
                }

                var batchResponse = new BatchResponse
                {
                    Key = key,
                    EventId = eventId,
                    StatusCode = httpResponseMsg.StatusCode,
                    ReasonPhrase = reasonPhrase
                };
                batchResponses.Add(batchResponse);
            }
        }

        if (failedReqKeys.Count == 0) return batchResponses;

        return await HandleFailedRequestsAsync(graphClient, failedReqKeys, batch, batchResponses).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

**HandleFailedRequestsAsync**

```
private async Task<List<BatchResponse>> HandleFailedRequestsAsync(IBaseClient graphClient, Dictionary<string, TimeSpan> failedReqKeys, BatchRequestContent batch, List<BatchResponse> batchResponses)
    {
        // Sleep for the duration as suggested in RetryAfter
        var sleepDuration = failedReqKeys.Values.Max();
        Thread.Sleep(sleepDuration);

        var failedBatchRequests = batch.BatchRequestSteps.Where(b => failedReqKeys.Keys.Contains(b.Key)).ToList();

        var failedBatch = new BatchRequestContent();
        foreach (var kvp in failedBatchRequests)
        {
            failedBatch.AddBatchRequestStep(kvp.Value);
        }

        var failedBatchResponses = await ExecuteBatchRequestAsync(graphClient, failedBatch);
        batchResponses.AddRange(failedBatchResponses);

        return batchResponses;
    }
```

I'm getting an error as [image: Unable to deserialize content] on the first line in method *ExecuteBatchRequestAsync* as

> Microsoft.Graph.ClientException: Code: invalidRequest
> Message: Unable to deserialize content.
> ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.

Can anyone nudge me where I'm doing wrong?